# Dev Express styling and HTML5 compliance

Tags: html, devexpress, w3c-validation

The Dev express controls I am using are being rendered with embedded styling.
Using the HTML5 check http://validator.w3.org/check is telling me embedded CSS is not cool. Is there a way to make dev express controls render the css as inline/external?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, DX do not guarantee that HTML code passed HTML5 doctype validation.

[XHTML 1.0 Transitional Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Core/xhtml.xml)

[HTML5 and XHTML Strict - New Doctypes Supported for ASP.NET Products](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/04/13/html-5-and-xhtml-strict-new-doctypes-supported-for-asp-net-products-coming-soon-in-v2011-volume-1.aspx)

You'll probably see warnings due to the doctype conflict.

Comment: I believe you can share your feedback with DX guys.